# Iphone libcurl WITH SSL enabled..?

Tags: iphone, ssl, libcurl

Has anyone had any luck building libCurl WITH SSL (openSSL) enabled for the Iphone...?

If so, could you recommend the versions you used and your cmd line config / build options...?

Preferably Non-Xcode answers...

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

As I suspected... No one had a clue...

So I'll answer my own question.

My hat's off to "Olipion!" Great Work...

http://sites.google.com/site/olipion/cross-compilation/libcurl